# Proof that any $\epsilon$-greedy policy is an improvement over any $\epsilon$-soft policy

Tags: monte-carlo, reinforcement-learning, deterministic-policy, stochastic-policy

In the book by Richard Sutton and Andrew Barto, "Reinforcement Learning - An Introduction", 2ed edition, at page 101 there is a proof, and I don't understand 1 passage of it.

We want to prove that any $\epsilon$-greedy policy with respect to an action-value function $q_\pi$ is an improvement over any $\epsilon$-soft policy $\pi$ is assured by the policy improvement theorem. Let $\pi'$ be the $\epsilon$-greedy policy. The conditions of the policy improvement theorem apply because for any $s \in \mathcal{S}$:

\begin{align}
q_{\pi}(s, \pi'(s))  &= \sum\limits_a \pi'(a\mid s) q_{\pi}(s,a) \\
&= \dfrac{\epsilon}{|\mathcal{A}|} \sum\limits_a q_{\pi}(s,a) + (1-\epsilon) \max\limits_a q_{\pi}(s,a) \\
& \ge \dfrac{\epsilon}{|\mathcal{A}|} \sum\limits_a q_{\pi}(s,a) + (1-\epsilon) \sum\limits_a \dfrac{\pi(a\mid s)-\dfrac{\epsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|}}{1-\epsilon} q_\pi(s,a)
\end{align}

I did not understand this last passage. The book now has a note which tries to explain this passage:

> (the sum is a weighted average with non-negative weights summing to 1,
> and as such it must be less than or equal to the largest number
> averaged)

But this still doesn't help me understand this last passage.

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/377473/monte-carlo-epsilon-greedy-policy-is-better-than-epsilon-soft-policy) asks for the passage from line 1 to line 2, I am asking for the passage from line 2 to line 3.

Comment: Are you asking why the claim in note is true, or how to verify that these weights sum up to 1?

Comment: I am asking why the last inequality is true

Comment: The note tells you why it follows from the previous line, so the question is which parts of the note you need help understanding with

Comment: Well the first part, why it is a weighted average that sums to 1. Thank you

Comment: The weighted average does not sum to 1, the weights in front of $q_\pi(s,a)$ do, here's why: 
$\pi(a|s)$ presumably sums to 1 over all $a$. Then the sum of the weights can be written as $\frac{1}{1-\epsilon} - |A| \cdot\frac{\epsilon}{ (1-\epsilon) \cdot |A|}$ which is 1

Comment: why the first equality holds?

Comment: I changed $\varepsilon-$greedy and $\varepsilon-$soft to $\varepsilon$-greedy and $\varepsilon$-soft. The correct usage here is a hyphen, not a minus sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also spent some trying to understand this transition. I came up with this. Hope it helps.

$\pi$ is an $\epsilon-$soft policy. This implies that $\pi(a|s) \ge \frac{\epsilon}{|A(s)|}$ for all actions and states.

Let $S = \sum_{a} \frac{\pi(a|s) - \frac{\epsilon}{|A(s)|}}{1-\epsilon} = \frac{\sum_{a}\pi(a|s) - \sum_{a}\frac{\epsilon}{|A(s)|}}{1-\epsilon} = \frac{1 - \frac{|A(s)|\epsilon}{|A(s)|}}{1-\epsilon} = 1 $

Let $w_{a} = \frac{\pi(a|s) - \frac{\epsilon}{|A(s)|}}{1-\epsilon}$ so $S=\sum_{a}w_{a} =1 $

The 2nd part of the equation at line 3 becomes equal to $\sum_{a} \frac{\pi(a|s) - \frac{\epsilon}{|A(s)|}}{1-\epsilon}q_{\pi}(s,a) = \sum_a w_{a}q_{\pi}(s,a)$ which is a weighted average with weights $w_{a}$ with $w_{a} \ge 0$ for all actions since the policy is $\epsilon-$soft.

Since $S$ is equal to 1 then $w_{a} \le 1$ for all actions and the weighted sum $\sum_a w_{a}q_{\pi}(s,a)$ "must be less than or equal to the largest number averaged" which is $\max_{a}q_{\pi}(s,a)$.

And we conclude that: 
$\sum_{a} \frac{\pi(a|s) - \frac{\epsilon}{|A(s)|}}{1-\epsilon}q_{\pi}(s,a) \le \max_{a}q_{\pi}(s,a)$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now

Comment: why $ q_{\pi}(s,\pi^{'}(s)) = \sum_{a}\pi^{'}(a|s)q(s,a)$  holds? It really confuses me