# One small confusion on $\epsilon$-Greedy policy improvement based on Monte Carlo

Tags: monte-carlo, reinforcement-learning, policy-iteration

I'm working on the RL book of Barto and Sutton, the author has provided the proof based on the policy improvement theorem, I can fully understand the inequality, but for the first equality, it really confuses me. why does $ q_{\pi}(s,\pi^{'}(s)) = \sum_{a}\pi^{'}(a|s)q(s,a)$ holds？ I guess the reason here is because  $\pi^{'}$ is stochastic, but where the summation come from?

[image]

Comment: @Neil Slater I have posted the question here, thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [page 96](https://web.stanford.edu/class/psych209/Readings/SuttonBartoIPRLBook2ndEd.pdf), the formula is stated.

It defines how can we evaluate the $q$-value for the policy $\pi'(s)$.

Given state $s$, $\pi'(a|s)$ is the probability that action $a$ is taken given that we are at state $s$ and if we take action $a$, we should expect a $q$-value of $q_{\pi}(s,a)$. We should then consider all possible cases and sum them up due to the [total law of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

$$E(R|S)=\sum_a P(A=a|S)E(R|s,A=a)$$

where $R$ is the reward, $S$ is the state, and $A$ is the action.

Comment: Appreciate the help, yes, I understand now. But based on the definition, $q_{\pi}(s ,a)=E(R|S,A)$, so $q_{\pi}(s ,{\pi}')$ should be something like $E(R|S,A'={\pi}')$?

Comment: I think on page $96$, the meaning of evaluating the $q$ value when the action is replaced by a policy is defined and it has to be defined based on entities that have been defined earlier. $q(s,a)$ is defined earlier.